# What is the Diff between sleep() of java & sleep() of c ?

Tags: java, c, ubuntu

I was using Java to test my code & i used threads . I converted that same code into c.

```
#include<pthread.h>
```

I have used above in c. So i just want to know that is there any difference between sleep() of Java & sleep() of c because in java its working fine but in c its not responding at all.

Comment: So your question is actually "why doesn't my C code work?"?

Comment: The the POSIX `sleep(x)` uses seconds, the java version uses milliseconds.

Comment: So put simply, your question is: _"What's the difference between C functions that have the same name as an existing Java function?"_

Comment: C likes to sleep a little bit more since it runs very fast :-p

Comment: @Oliver yes Exactly...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Pretty sure you’ve got that backwards: C has seniority. It should be *“What's the difference between Java functions that have the same name as an C Java function?”* :)

Answer (score 3):

C function is defined as `sleep(unsigned int seconds);`

Java function as `Thread.sleep(long millis).`

While the functions are similar, meaning of parameter is different. `Thread.sleep(1000)` in Java will stop your thread for a second, and `sleep(1000)` in C will freeze it for what seems like forever.

In C there are functions with better precision: on Windows you have Sleep from windows.h, and in Linux you have usleep and nanosleep for microseconds and nanoseconds arguments respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use

```
#include<unistd.h>
```

On windows, you would use:

```
#include<windows.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep` is a windows function.  On Unix/Linux use `usleep`.  Note that `usleep` takes microseconds, not milliseconds.

**> Updated**

older [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standards defined [`usleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html), so this is available on Linux:

> ```
>    int usleep(useconds_t usec);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The  usleep()  function  suspends execution of the calling process for
>          (at least) usec microseconds.  The sleep may be lengthened slightly by
>          any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the
>          granularity of system timers.

`usleep()` takes **microseconds**, so you will have to multiply the input by 1000 in order to sleep in milliseconds.

---

`usleep()` has since been deprecated and subsequently removed from POSIX; for new code, [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) is preferred:

> ```
>    #include <time.h>
>
>    int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> `nanosleep()` suspends the execution of the calling thread until either at least the time specified in `*req` has elapsed, or the
>   delivery of a signal that triggers the invocation of a handler in the
>   calling thread or that terminates the process.
>
> The structure timespec is used to specify intervals of time with nanosecond precision.  It is defined as follows:
>
> ```
>        struct timespec {
>            time_t tv_sec;        /* seconds */
>            long   tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
>        };
> ```